Error when installing kubelet from yum repo on Amazon Linux 2023
I tried to roughly follow Kubernetes the Hard Way to install Kubernetes from scratch. But I did it on AWS Graviton (Arm64) nodes with Amazon Linux 2023, mostly using cloud-init.
I installed most of the dependencies listed in Bootstrapping Kubernetes Worker Nodes from Amazons own repositories, with this part of cloud-init.
#cloud-config

packages: ['runc', 'containerd', 'cni-plugins', 'socat', 'conntrack-tools', 'ipset']

But that repository did not contain the Kubernetes binaries, so I added the official Kubernetes Yum repository to the cloud-init config.
yum_repos:
  kubernetes:
    baseurl: https://pkgs.k8s.io/core:/stable:/v1.28/rpm/
    name: Kubernetes
    gpgcheck: true
    gpgkey: https://pkgs.k8s.io/core:/stable:/v1.28/rpm/repodata/repomd.xml.key
    exclude: kubeadm cri-tools kubernetes-cni

Then when I logged in on the VM instance, I tried to install the Kubelet binary with:
sudo dnf install kubelet

But I got errors (see below) that it depends on kubernetes-cni. However, that is what I have opted out from, since I use the cni-plugins binary from Amazon's repository. As how I understand it, cni-plugins are an alternative CNI implementation to kubernetes-cni. Also the Kubernetes The Hard Way do the same choice, to use cni-plugins instead of kubernetes-cni.
But why can I not install the kubelet binary from the repo without kubernetes-cni binary? Is this just a missing configuration from Kubernetes side, or have I misunderstood something from the Kubernetes The Hard Way guide about what binaries are required for worker nodes?
Error:
 Problem: conflicting requests
  - package kubelet-1.28.0-150500.1.1.aarch64 from kubernetes requires kubernetes-cni >= 1.2.0, but none of the providers can be installed
  - package kubelet-1.28.1-150500.1.1.aarch64 from kubernetes requires kubernetes-cni >= 1.2.0, but none of the providers can be installed
  - package kubelet-1.28.2-150500.1.1.aarch64 from kubernetes requires kubernetes-cni >= 1.2.0, but none of the providers can be installed
  - package kubelet-1.28.3-150500.1.1.aarch64 from kubernetes requires kubernetes-cni >= 1.2.0, but none of the providers can be installed
  - package kubelet-1.28.4-150500.1.1.aarch64 from kubernetes requires kubernetes-cni >= 1.2.0, but none of the providers can be installed
  - package kubelet-1.28.5-150500.1.1.aarch64 from kubernetes requires kubernetes-cni >= 1.2.0, but none of the providers can be installed
  - package kubelet-1.28.6-150500.1.1.aarch64 from kubernetes requires kubernetes-cni >= 1.2.0, but none of the providers can be installed
  - package kubelet-1.28.7-150500.1.1.aarch64 from kubernetes requires kubernetes-cni >= 1.2.0, but none of the providers can be installed
  - package kubelet-1.28.8-150500.1.1.aarch64 from kubernetes requires kubernetes-cni >= 1.2.0, but none of the providers can be installed


If I drop kubernetes-cni from the exclude: part in cloud-init, and install kubelet with kubernetes-cni as a dependency, I get a conflict error:
Error: Transaction test error:
  file /opt/cni/bin/bandwidth from install of kubernetes-cni-1.2.0-150500.2.1.aarch64 conflicts with file from package cni-plugins-1.2.0-1.amzn2023.0.3.aarch64
  file /opt/cni/bin/bridge from install of kubernetes-cni-1.2.0-150500.2.1.aarch64 conflicts with file from package cni-plugins-1.2.0-1.amzn2023.0.3.aarch64
  file /opt/cni/bin/dhcp from install of kubernetes-cni-1.2.0-150500.2.1.aarch64 conflicts with file from package cni-plugins-1.2.0-1.amzn2023.0.3.aarch64
  file /opt/cni/bin/dummy from install of kubernetes-cni-1.2.0-150500.2.1.aarch64 conflicts with file from package cni-plugins-1.2.0-1.amzn2023.0.3.aarch64
  file /opt/cni/bin/firewall from install of kubernetes-cni-1.2.0-150500.2.1.aarch64 conflicts with file from package cni-plugins-1.2.0-1.amzn2023.0.3.aarch64

